# how do i change the value of an object

Tags: c#

here is my main method:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine(); // 2006 2000 false 1000 500 Windows
List<string> inputs = input.Split(" ").ToList();
Computer one = new Computer(int.Parse(inputs[0]), int.Parse(inputs[1]), bool.Parse(inputs[2]), double.Parse(inputs[3]), double.Parse(inputs[4]), inputs[5]);
one.Print(); // 2006, 2000, false, 1000, 500, Windows
input = Console.ReadLine(); //changeOperatingSystem
if (input == "changeOperatingSystem")
{
string newOperationSystem = Console.ReadLine(); //Linux
Computer two = new Computer(newOperationSystem);
}
one.Print(); //2006, 2000, false, 1000, 500, Linux
```

the "//" marks what the input and the output look like.
This is my Computer.cs:

```
private int years;
        private int price;
        private bool isNotebook;
        private double hardDiskMemory;
        private double freeMemory;
        private string operationSystem;
        private string newOperationSystem;

        public Computer(int years, int price, bool isNotebook, double hardDiskMemory, double freeMemory, string operationSystem)
        {
            Years = years;
            Price = price;
            IsNotebook = isNotebook;
            HardDiskMemory = hardDiskMemory;
            FreeMemory = freeMemory;
            OperationSystem = operationSystem;
        }
        public Computer(string newOperationSystem)
        {
            OperationSystem = newOperationSystem;
        }
        public int Years
        {
            get { return years; }
            set
            {
                years = value;
            }
        }
        public int Price
        {
            get { return price; }
            set
            {
                price = value;
            }
        }
        public bool IsNotebook
        {
            get { return isNotebook; }
            set
            {
                isNotebook = value;
            }
        }
        public double HardDiskMemory
        {
            get { return hardDiskMemory; }
            set
            {
                hardDiskMemory = value;
            }
        }
        public double FreeMemory
        {
            get { return freeMemory; }
            set
            {
                freeMemory = value;
            }
        }
        public string OperationSystem
        {
            get { return operationSystem; }
            set
            {
                operationSystem = value;
            }
        }
        
        public string NewOperationSystem
        {
            get { return NewOperationSystem; }
            set
            {
                newOperationSystem = value;
            }
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{years}, {price}, {isNotebook}, {hardDiskMemory}, {FreeMemory}, {operationSystem}");
        }
```

what I want this program to do is whenever the input submitted by the user is `"changeOperationSystem"` the program gives the user another input where they submit the new Operation system for the pc. Then with the constructor, the Computer.Cs receives the string `newOperationSystem`, which then should replace the value `operationSystem` as I tried to do in the constructor: `OperationSystem = newOperationSystem`, but it doesn't work. I am stil learning classes so don't go hard on me.

Comment: `Computer two = new Computer(newOperationSystem);` creates a new object that is completely unrelated to the first object and stores the referecne to it in a completely separate variable. Perhaps you meant to write `one = new Computer(newOperationSystem);` instead?

Comment: or `one.OperationSystem = newOperationSystem;`

Comment: To be honest I kinda free-form coded it and expected it to work. It was that easy and I wrote so many lines for nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you are trying to change one property of a class. All you have to do is use the property set method

```
one.OperationSystem = newOperationSystem;
```

and remove the property `NewOperationSystem` altogether.

Here is a bare bones skeleton code of instantiating a class with a constructor and then changing one of the properties

```
public class Foo
{
    private int _a;
    private string _b;
    private readonly float _c;

    public Foo(int a, string b, float c)
    {
        _a = a;
        _b = b;
        _c = c;
    }

    public int A { get => _a; set => _a = value; }
    public string B { get => _b; set => _b = value; }
    public float C => _c;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{_a}, {_b}, {_c}";
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo one = new Foo(100, "Philip", 0.75f);

        Console.WriteLine(one);
        //100, Philip, 0.75

        one.B = "Spencer";

        Console.WriteLine(one);
        //100, Spencer, 0.75
        
    }
}
```

Another feature of the code above is that there is no need to create a `.Print()` method, if you can take advantage of the built-in `.ToString()` which gets called automatically during a `Console.WriteLine()` or any other operations that require a string input from my class.

Finally, I added a read-only property `C` to demonstrate that this design is possible. You will not be able to write `one.C = 0.25f;` since the property is read-only.